# VB-Script sleeps after calling VBA-Script

Tags: excel, sap-gui

since a few years I'm working with some scripts which are creating a report in SAP, saving the data into an Excel-File and processing these data with an VBA-Script in Excel.

Since a few days it doesn't work properly any more. Sometimes it works fine, but the next run it fails.
The data are processed by Excel but afterwards SAP doesn't stop running the VB-Script. Unfortunately I don't know the exact line where the script stops working.

Asking our IT-guy, he said that we changed our SAP-Gui and our Office to Office365 somewhen the last weeks.

This is the end of the code, starting with calling the VBA-Script.

```
'***** Report über Excel-Makro auswerten *****
wshell.run chr(34) & "\\denbppfs002\Abteilungslaufwerke\Produktion\Produktionsreporting\Makros\Autostart OpenProcessOrders.xlsm" & chr(34),1,true

'wscript.sleep 4000 

If Not IsObject(application) Then
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If

while connection.children.count > 0
Set asession = connection.Children(0)
asession.findbyid("wnd[0]").close
on error resume next
asession.findById("wnd[1]/usr/btnSPOP-OPTION1").press
on error goto 0
wend
```

Does anybody knows what the problem could be?

Thanks for your help,
Lutz

Comment: If you have an appropriate debugger installed on your system (e.g. Visual Studio), and it's setup properly, then when you run your script with `cscript.exe your_script_name.vbs //X //D` then you can step through your script one line at a time and see exactly where it is falling.

Comment: Hi Zev, unfortunately I don't have a debugger on my system.

Comment: I would first trim the script and remove the commands behind wshell.run. Then I would start the abridged script and see how it behaves. The remote lines only implement the closing of all open SAP sessions. Then I would put these lines in a new script and additionally provided with msgbox "position 1", msgbox "position 2", etc., so I know how far he has come in the processing or at what point in a loop rotates infinitely long.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I can think of is, are you sure you are disposing your VBA object that connects to SAP? I mean the part that gets called within "Autostart OpenProcessOrders.xlsm"

I think that the problem with your solution is that your next iteration cannot be called before current execution ends, SAP will allow you to run only one script at a time.

See here:

```
Public Sub GetWorkDone

    Dim SapGuiAuto As Object
    Dim app As SAPFEWSELib.GuiApplication
    Dim connection As SAPFEWSELib.GuiConnection
    Dim session As SAPFEWSELib.GuiSession

    On Error Goto Dispose
        
        Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
        Set app = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
        Set connection = app.Children(0)
        Set session = connection.Children(0)
        
        'Your code goes here
        
    On Error Goto 0

    Dispose:

        Set session = Nothing
        Set connection = Nothing
        Set app = Nothing
        Set SapGuiAuto = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

This way, whenever your code goes banana or the program just ends, all of the objects are being set to "Nothing".

Let me know if that helped!